# What type of regression to use when outcome is integers from 0 to 10

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, count-data, ordered-logit

I have an outcome variable that measures "community perception," with responses ranging from $0$ to $10$. For instance, the outcome variable might represent answers to the question: "In your neighborhood, out of every $10$ people, how many own a car?" I also have three independent variables, which are binary and can take values of $0$ or $1$.

I'm uncertain about the appropriate regression analysis for this scenario. I was considering Poisson regression, as the distribution of the outcome variable doesn't appear to be "bunched up" in either $0$ near $10$. I've also thought about using Ordinal Logistic Regression, but I'm not sure if it's suitable.

Do you have any suggestions about which regression to use?

Comment: I like @Shawn Hemelstrand 's answer, which he deleted. But I'm wondering why he deleted it.

Comment: I was a bit concerned about whether or not it translates to a limited range of values, but I will add it back in in case others believe it is useful (or criticize it if wrong).

Comment: Not the issue, but it's a terrible question. Who counts as people? Does it really mean households or famiilies, themselves fuzzy notions? What does neighborhood mean? How or how well do people know these facts about their neighbours? Are fractional parts allowed? I suppose there's a defence that it's _perception_ that is being measured.

Comment: That was another concern I had. This measure is fairly subjective and doesn't concretely measure what they are after (from what I assume), but as you say thats a different issue.

Comment: I look out of my window and see various cars in the street. I recognise our car as ours, but I have no idea otherwise who owns what or which cars are visiting or how many people live in every house nearby  Set-ups do vary (what about apartments, etc., etc.), but I rest my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally posted a much longer answer on count models until I saw a key detail that I missed earlier:

> I have an outcome variable that measures "community perception," with
> responses **ranging from 0 to 10**.

Your data here is not just bounded at zero, it is also bounded at ten. Because of this, modeling a regression with a simple Poisson distribution may not be the most accurate because you would need to account for this potential ceiling of values, which your regression would be unable to predict accurately. For example, if we tried to predict what someone's count would be if it exceeded $10$, our model would not extrapolate well.

What you could do instead is treat these as proportional values. For example, if I answer $4$, then we could transform this into $4/10 = .40$. Then these responses could be modeled as proportions instead of counts, and thus this could be modeled with a simple quasi-binomial regression instead.